# What is the name of the part (1st picture)?

Tags: honda, part-identification, oil-leak, crv, gasket

I could see the oil leak starts from this black rounded part (1st picture). The vehicle is Honda CR-V 2001. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a "Camshaft Cap Gasket" or "Cylinder Head Plug". It seals the end of where your camshaft goes to keep the oil in the right places (ie: Inside the engine.) The OEM part number for this is: [12513P72003](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=83vfW6rCDca4zwKSl5uQBQ&q=honda+12513P72003)

Answer (score 0):

Its a Cylinder Head Plug or Camshaft Cap Gasket. Either name will work.